# C programming- How to check if array index contains a specific character (-n)?

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    if (argv[1] == '-n')
    {
        printf("Hello");
    }
}
```

When I run this, I'm getting a "warning- comparison between pointer and integer" error. How do I fix this?

I checked that `argv[1]` contains `-n` by printing.

Comment: `argv` is an array of *strings*. `'-n'` is a multi-character constant, not a string. Not that you use `==` to compare strings anyway.

Comment: Yes, that is a duplicate. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: -n isn't a character...

Answer (score 1):

The `argv[1]` value represents a *string*, which is a character pointer type, while `'-n'` is a multi-byte character constant (an integer). That's why you're getting the `"pointer and integer"` mismatch.

You should be using *string* comparison functions here, such as:

```
// Make sure you HAVE an argument, then use string comparison to check.

if ((argc > 1) && (strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0)) {
    printf("hello"); 
}
```